# Pruning posts in the community discussion list

Tags: discussion-board, community

I would like to make my discussion list (on the community site) automatically prune discussions (entire thread) that has not been modified in 3 days. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best way to accomplish this?

I would prefer not to have the discussions deleted, but instead moved to an archive (not yet created). Not sure if archiving a thread will impact a users reputation, but ideally I'd like to leave their reputation alone if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I used discussion board for a notice-board and I had your same problem.
To resolve it, I added *a boolean field to le list*. ( `Archived`)
Then I deployed a custom *web part* to show **the notice not archived**.
A daily **timer job** was updating the item. (I used expiration day).

Hope it helps ;)